# Does int in (SELECT varchar...) work?

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to modify some code written bey somebody else that is generating a model for a report being built in Business Intelligence Development Studio (Microsoft Reporting Services).

I was wondering if this is necessary?

```
WHERE (convert(varchar,R.Kommunenr) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split('"+ @kommune+ "', ',') AS Split_1))"
```

$kommune is a text built up like this: "kommune1,kommune2,kommune3,..."

Is it okay to check that an int (R.kommunenr) is IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split('"+ @kommune+ "', ',') AS Split_1) which I reckon is a varchar. Like this

```
WHERE (R.Kommunenr IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.Split('"+ @kommune+ "', ',') AS Split_1))
```

The problem is I can't run the code, as I atm only have the code, and not permission to run it.

Comment: As an aside, aliasing the Split function in this particular case is definitely *not* necessary (can work both ways).

Answer (score 0):

In `TSQL` implicit conversions, `VARCHAR` are cast into `INT` and not vice versa.

So your second query will fail if `r.kommunenr` is an `INT` and `dbo.split` returns a `VARCHAR` not castable into an `INT`.

If you want to benefit from an index on `r.kommunenr`, you may try this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    r
WHERE   kommunenr IN
        (
        SELECT  CASE IsNumeric(item)
                WHEN 1
                THEN
                        CASE
                        WHEN CAST(item AS FLOAT) = CAST(CAST(item AS FLOAT) AS INT)
                        THEN
                                CAST(CAST(item AS FLOAT) AS INT)
                        END
                END
        FROM    dbo.split(@kommune) split1
        )
```

This will handle edge cases like `1E8` which is numeric but not directly castable to `INT`.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms177682(v=SQL.90).aspx Could I interpret this as the _test expression_ and the _subquery_ **must** be the exact same data type? If the _test expression_ is int and the _subquery_ is varchar, what will happen? The reason I'm asking is when the query is run, everything is included. I thought one might expect an error, or none rows. Maybe the problem is some other part of the code...

Comment: @Øyvind: this query:`SELECT 1 WHERE CAST(1 AS INT) IN (SELECT CAST('1' AS NVARCHAR))` succeeds, this one: `SELECT 1 WHERE CAST(1 AS INT) IN (SELECT CAST('string' AS NVARCHAR))` fails with a runtime error. Please post the definition of your table.

Comment: The subquery in your example should be filtered to *exclude* rows for which `ISNUMERIC()` returns `0` as well as those where the numbers are not integers. Otherwise it would return NULLs in the mentioned cases, which would cause the `IN` operator [to return `UNKNOWN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177682.aspx), in conformity to the ternary logic.

Comment: @Andriy: please run this: `SELECT 1 WHERE 1 IN (SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT NULL)`

Comment: @Quassnoi: Yes, it works no problem. Seems like I've read a bit too much into it, for their particular wording explains that the expected result *is* possible: *'Using null values in together with IN or NOT IN **can** produce unexpected results'*. So, it can produce unexpected results, though not necessarily it will. Still, I would rather play safe by getting rid of NULLs.